Update the id field in the cosmosDB document
I am trying to update the id field in the cosmosDB with the python script.
But I get the below error,
2024-09-11 12:59:51,301 - ERROR - An error occurred: Id contains illegal chars.
There are no illegal characters in the ID.
Current Id:
 PIN-KM-12 Ergo-15072024-11-test1|WestRock-K|Alexandria,OH|Alexandria,OH|Change Scenario Title - 51cea393-f42a-4a1c-a388-a5ea78cabf12|Change Scenario Title - 51cea393-f42a-4a1c-a388-a5ea78cabf12|Corrugate|Regular slotted|United States of America (the)|PFNA|mckinsey_src_data_template|mckinsey_should_cost_scenario_template`
`Current id Byte length: 321

New Id:
 PIN-KM-12 Ergo-15072024-11-test1|WestRock-K|Alexandria,OH|Alexandria,OH|United States of America (the)|PFNA|Corrugate|Regular slotted|Change Scenario Title - 51cea393-f42a-4a1c-a388-a5ea78cabf12|mckinsey_src_data_template|mckinsey_should_cost_scenario_template|2024|CPU|TL
new id Byte length: 272

Why does it fail? Is there any limit to the Id field length? The below official documentation states its 1023 bytes. (Under pre-item limits)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits
Then why I get the error?
I am checking the length by below code,
byte_length = len(current_id.encode('utf-8'))
newbyte_length = len(new_id.encode('utf-8'))

